# C, checking if the first character of an input is a certain letter

Tags: c

For an assignment I need to receive an input (in C), always starting with a letter and followed by either a space or \n, like for example

```
A 123456 abcde
B 123
C
```

These letters are used to define which function to call and the following info will be the parameters used in the function.

I'm having major difficulties receiving the input and then moving forwards.
I've tried splitting the input at " " with strtok and making it into an array but can't really get anywhere with that. I also can't find a way to check if an element of the array is a certain letter like:
if ((str[0] == "A") != 0) { -->

any suggestions? <3

Comment: 'If (str[0] == 'A') { '   yes, it really is that simple, note: single quotes to identify a character constant).

Comment: What is `!= 0` for?

Comment: Post your attempts to write the program. A single incorrect line of code isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((str[0] == "A") != 0)
```

This do not work because `"A"` is a string while `str[0]`is a char. Your compiler should emit a warning.

This is  what you want to do:

```
if ((str[0] == 'A') != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I might do it

First define the functions

```
void A(int n, const char *p) {
    printf("function A with %d and \"%s\"\n", n, p);
}
void B(int n) {
    printf("function B with %d\n", n);
}
void C(void) {
    printf("function C\n");
}
```

Then, in main, get the input, process it and call the function

```
    char str[1000];
    if (!fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    switch (str[0]) {
        default:
            /*error*/;
            break;
        case 'A': 
            char *next;
            int n = strtol(str + 2, &next, 10); // needs error checking and validation
            if (*next != ' ') /*error*/;
            A(n, next + 1);
            break;
        case 'B':
            int n = strtol(str + 2, NULL, 10); // needs error checking and validation
            B(n);
            break;
        case 'C':
            C();
            break;
    }
```